# Почему shell_exec ничего не возвращает?

Tags: php

Цель такая - один скрипт может запускать/убивать другие скрипты-демоны. Для этого я использую `shell_exec()`, сохраняю PID и потом управляю процессами через функцию `shell_exec()`. Это в принципе нормально?
Возник вопрос относительно использования этой функции. Вот фрагмент кода скрипта, который должен запускать демона:

```
echo exec('php -f testd.php &');
```

После этой строки скрипт ничего не выводит, а приостанавливает свое выполнение, будто чего-то ожидая. В это время демон `testd.php` работает. После принудительной остановки скрипта, демон тоже прекращает свою работу. При этом если выполнить такую же команду `php -f testd.php &` в терминале, то всё работает так, как и задумано - демон запускается отдельным процессом и в терминал выводится его PID. Но весь вывод демона попадает в тот же терминал, из которого он был запущен, так ведь не должно быть... Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации к [exec](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php) написано:

> Для получения вывода исполняемой программы, убедитесь, что параметр
>   output инициализирован и используется.

Я подозреваю, что нужно сделать как-то так:

```
$output = array();
exec($command , $output);
print_r($output);
```

> После этой строки скрипт ничего не выводит, а приостанавливает свое
>   выполнение, будто чего-то ожидая.

Он ожидает конца выполнения вашего демона. Добавьте к вашей команде вывод в `/dev/null` вот так `php -f testd.php > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!`. Тогда скрипт не будет ждать завершения демона и получит pid.

Comment: оутпут должен быть массивом

Comment: @L.Vadim спасибо, поправил

Comment: Если выводить массив, то нужно `var_dump($output);`. Насчет переопределения вывода, мне ведь еще нужно получить `PID` нового процесса, а так я получаю пустой массив. Можно ли как-нибудь получить только PID и ничего кроме него?

Comment: @Rochfort you welcome :)

Comment: @LNK Можно получить PID просто поставить еще одну переменную $pid = exec($command, $response);

Comment: @LNK а если не секрет, зачем вам pid процесса ? Какую логику вы хотите на него возложить ?

Comment: @Rochfort, в вопросе я же написал, что скрипт должен уметь еще и убивать процессы. Для этого мне и нужен PID.

Comment: @L.Vadim переменная `$pid` остается пуста.

Comment: @LNK В той же документации в [комментарии](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php#88704) говорят что получить pid можно так `php -f testd.php > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!`. Надо проверить.

Comment: @LNK а так : $proc = proc_open('yourcommand', $descriptorspec, $pipes);

Comment: $descriptorspec = [
    0 => ['pipe', 'r'],
    1 => ['pipe', 'w'],
    2 => ['pipe', 'w']
];

Comment: @Rochfort, да, теперь всё работает так, как нужно. Спасибо. Дополните свой ответ информацией из комментария.

Comment: @L.Vadim, я отметил тот ответ. Решение Rochfort, хотя и взято из комментариев к документации, более компактно, чем ваше и занимает одну простую строку кода.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$response = array()
exec('whoami', $response);
print_r($response,true);
?>
```